# Python Kivy, Unable to add Label to screen with Python

Tags: python, widget, screen, kivy

I am trying to add a simple label to a screen using Python and Kivy. I know how to do it using the Builder.load_string() method, but I wish to do it using the Kivy library through Python.

When I run the code below I get a blank purple screen, but when I put the label into the Builder.load_string() method it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_string("""
<HomePage>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: .5,0,.75
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
""")


class HomePage(Screen):
    layout = FloatLayout()
    home_title = Label(text="text")
    layout.add_widget(home_title)


class LabelApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(HomePage(name='home'))
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    LabelApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do: if you always want to add these widgets to `HomePage`, you should do this in `HomePage`'s `__init__` method (don't forget to add `self.add_widget(layout)` there.

You could also just add them in `LabelApp`s `build` method. Just assign the `HomePage` to a variable, and again use `add_widget` on that.

Comment: Ok, now I need to understand why something I did worked. I tried using just the def __init__(self): and adding layout, but it gave an error:

AttributeError: 'HomePage' object has no attribute '_trigger_layout'

Then I added one extra line but I do not understand why it fixed my problems. I added the super line shown below, then tried replacing it with the Screen.init line below. Both worked, why?

super(HomePage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
Screen.__init__(self)

Comment: @jdanaher make sure to call `super`. See examples [in kivy's basic guide](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/basic.html#customize-the-application).

Comment: Thank you, that was quite a helpful read! Can I call super on each screen that overloads the Screen class?

Comment: @jdanaher maybe you should check out a tutorial about classes and inheritance in python. In general, you call `super` whenever you define a subclass of something and overwrite the `__init__` method. In this particular  case, `super(HomePage, self)` returns `Screen`.

Comment: Ah alright, yes. I was struggling with inheritance in python for a problem I had earlier this week and ended up deciding on a workaround. I'll focus on figuring that out first now. Much thanks!